# q $\in \mathbb{Q}$ then $1 \otimes_\mathbb{Z} q$ = $q \otimes_\mathbb{Z} 1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

I've been shown that $\mathbb{Q} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Q} \cong \mathbb{Q}$ where $f:\mathbb{Q} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}$ where $f(p \otimes q) = p \cdot q$. But if this is true, then $p \otimes q = q \otimes p$. I wasn't able to show this. I've tried mostly using that $\otimes$ is $\mathbb{Z}$-balanced. Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

We have indeed
$$\frac{a}{b}\otimes_\mathbb{Z}1 = \frac{1}{b}\otimes_\mathbb{Z}a=\frac{1}{b}\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\frac{ab}{b}=1\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\frac{a}{b}\ .$$
Where is your problem with this?

Comment: It's perfect. I didn't thought of writing $a$ as $\frac{a \cdot b}{b}$ Thanks

Answer (score 1):

$f$ being injective has $f(p\otimes q)=p.q=qp=f(q\otimes p)\Rightarrow p\otimes q=q\otimes p.$